# Check Internetconnection and Online Status of Server

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

```
    public static bool CheckOnlineStatus()
    {

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.energy.ch");
        WebResponse response = request.getResponse();
        if (response == null || response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I want to check the Internetconnection and the check if the Server is Online with the Code above. But VS2010 says that there is no definition for the Methode getResponse in Webrequest.
(Same Problem with StatusCode in response.) Can somebody see my mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`WebRequest.GetResponse` doesn't exist on Silverlight. You have to use the asynchronous methods `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse`.

For StatusCode, you have first to cast your WebResponse to a HttpWebResponse:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
```

Comment: and what do i have to do with the asyncResult? is this a Function?

Comment: Here is a sample on how to use BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse: http://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/making-an-asynchronous-webrequest/